# How create a table inside the selected database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, table, postgresql-10

This is the command to create a new database,

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

This is the command to create a new table,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ( int a PRIMARY KEY );
```

But this does not add the `mytable` inside the `mydb`. How to add the table inside the database `mydb`?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 (64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this does not add the mytable inside the mydb. How to add the table inside the database mydb?

You have to connect to the database `mydb`,

```
psql -d mydb
```

Then run the command

Comment: I get this error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"`.

Comment: Where? Did you put a space between the dash and the d? `-d`?

Comment: No space between `-` and `d`.

Comment: so where is that error coming from, I have no idea. Does your table name or column name have a `-` in it?

Comment: The database and table does not have `-`.

Comment: @CodenameK do you have anything in your `psqlrc`?

Comment: @CodenameK: you need to run that on the windows command line. That is **not**  a SQL statement. You simply start `psql` and connect to the new database. If you already started `psql` you need to use `\connect` to switch to a different database

Comment: `\connect` works and created the table in `mydb`. But when the database was dropped the table seems to still exists.

Comment: If the database is dropped, you can't connect to it to see if the table exists. And no one can be connected to the database that you're dropping. You have to drop it while connecting to a different database.

Comment: Let me check on this.